Python Sphinx autodoc and class decorator
I try to use sphinx to automatically generate documentation. My rst file looks like this:
.. automodule:: function
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

This works fine, except when function has a class decorator:
from functools import update_wrapper

class ClassDecorator(object):
    """
    This class is used as a decorator
    """
    def __init__(self, org_function):
        self.org_function = org_function
        update_wrapper(self, org_function)

@ClassDecorator
def function()
    """
    The original docstring
    """
    pass

In this case nothing shows up in the documentation. I also tried autoclass, autofunction and autodecorator, but none of them works. How can I get the original docstring of function in my documentation?
